# shift selection not working for rebound M-{ backward-paragraph

Tags: key-bindings, paragraphs, shift-selection

I slightly simplified the keys for `backward-paragraph` and `forward-paragraph`:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-{"))  ;; originally backward-paragraph
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-}"))  ;; originally forward-paragraph
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[") 'backward-paragraph)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-]") 'forward-paragraph)
```

These work, but I was hoping to get Shift Selection for free. In particular, [the official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shift-Selection.html) says:

> If you hold down the shift key while typing a cursor motion command,
>   this sets the mark before moving point, so that the region extends
>   from the original position of point to its new position. This feature
>   is referred to as shift-selection. It is similar to the way text is
>   selected in other editors.
>
> ...
>
> Shift-selection only works if the shifted cursor motion key is not
>   already bound to a separate command (see Customization). For example,
>   if you bind S-C-f to another command, typing S-C-f runs that command
>   instead of performing a shift-selected version of C-f (forward-char).

I have `shift-select-mode` as its default value, which is `t`.

However, if I now press `M-{`, I just get `M-{ is undefined` in the echo area, instead of shift-selected `backward-paragraph` as I was hoping. This seems to contradict the passage from the manual above. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**edit**: I also tried the following, [taken from a similar question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36917/meta-based-navigation-shift-selection):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[")
        (lambda ()
          (interactive "^")
          (backward-paragraph)))
```

And this had the exact same result as my initial method; e.g. `M-[` effectively acts as `backward-paragraph`, but `M-{` just says `undefined`

Comment: Right, `(interactive "^")` only works for alphabet keybinding..

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in emacs; `M-{` should just automatically work, if we take the manual at face value.

As a workaround, I took an [answer to a similar question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22166/93) and modified it:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-[") 'backward-paragraph)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-{") 'backward-paragraph-with-shift-select)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-]") 'forward-paragraph)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-}") 'forward-paragraph-with-shift-select)

(defun backward-paragraph-with-shift-select ()
  (interactive)
  (setq this-command-keys-shift-translated t)
  (call-interactively 'backward-paragraph))

(defun forward-paragraph-with-shift-select ()
  (interactive)
  (setq this-command-keys-shift-translated t)
  (call-interactively 'forward-paragraph))
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: The manual page you've quoted is somewhat misleading in this respect.  `(elisp)Key Sequence Input` has a more specific explanation: shift selection occurs when "an input character is upper-case (or has the shift modifier) and has no key binding, but its lower-case equivalent has one".  The issue is that `M-{` is *not* `M-S-[`.